# How to delete multiple CRDS whose names contain the same string

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Can I delete multiple CRDS whose names contain the same string with a `kubectl`/`bash` one-liner?
For example I'd like to delete all the ones below:

```bash
kafkabridges.kafka.strimzi.io
kafkaconnectors.kafka.strimzi.io
kafkaconnects.kafka.strimzi.io
kafkamirrormaker2s.kafka.strimzi.io
kafkamirrormakers.kafka.strimzi.io
kafkarebalances.kafka.strimzi.io
kafkas.kafka.strimzi.io
kafkatopics.kafka.strimzi.io
kafkausers.kafka.strimzi.io
```

Answer (score 2):

Same logic; **kafka.strimzi.io** is the common string:

```
for crd in `kubectl get crds -oname | grep kafka.strimzi.io | awk -F / '{ print $2 }'`; do kubectl delete crd $crd; done
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is quite simple and does the job:

```bash
MATCH_STRING="kafka.strimzi.io"
kubectl get crds -oname | grep "$MATCH_STRING" | xargs kubectl delete
```

Answer (score 1):

All of them seem like contain/ending with `kafka.strimzi.io`, so the below command should work

```
 kubectl delete CustomResourceDefinition $(kubectl get CustomResourceDefinition -A | grep "kafka.strimzi.io" | awk '{print $1}')
```